# Inner layout design using DIVs

Tags: php, html, css

I need to create a page layout using DIVs. I can create basic layouts, but this one is a bit more complicated, please see pic attached for the layout. Is this possible? Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated...
[image]

Comment: Definitely it is possible.

Comment: I'd recommend using `float: left` and `width: __vw` rules (`vw` is a unit relative to viewport width). Start with that and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think there are two solutions:

**1 u can use a grid-system like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), there u also can float inner divs around others,**

**2 if the height is important or optional on all inner divs**, u can use a little workaround by merging divs with identical size together. in your layout, i would try to:

- create 4 "main divs" for inner divs 1 to 11, and the last three 12,13 and 14
- in the first main div, create one with floating left and fixed width for the inner divs 1,3 and 10
- let div 2 be as it is but margin left to the width of the div created in step 2
- create another div like #2 but for inner divs 4 to 8
- repeat step 3 for divs 9 and 11
- in the created div for 4 to 8, its the same like the first, just merge 4 and 5 together in one div, 6,7 and 8 in another - **dont forget the width and floating**
- make shure that u always clear the floating after div break eg first main to the second and in the merged ones
- if u want a fixed width on the whole layout, put a wrapper arround them or set all 4 main divs to the fixed width

-untestet- but **solution 2** works in many layouts for me, there u also can add responsive support, but bootstrap itself is already responsive. Choose on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` and `float:right`,`text-align: center` and percentage width for responsive layout